# ¿Cómo configurar DNS personalizado? Windows 10

Tags: dns, windows10, dominio

quisiera saber si alguien sabe como configurar mi `DNS` de manera que me quede el de Google y despues el interno para poder acceder al portal de la empresa, les explicó un poco en la empresa tienen bloqueado algunas paginas, y para poder acceder basta con cambiar el DNS por el de Google `8.8.8.8` y listo puedo acceder a cualquier sitio, pero no puedo acceder por el nombre del portal de la empresa `sistema.miempresa.com` tengo que meter la dirección `IP` entonces necesito tener tanto `8.8.8.8` y `192.168.1.254` para que cuando busque si no encuentra en uno busque en el otro pero por más que he movido no logro comprender como deberias de hacerlo. Gracias por su atención.  Adjuntos imagenes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución simple es editar el archivo de hosts (situado en %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc , abre el notepad como administrador para que te deje modificarlo) y añade la entrada de *sistema.miempresa.com* con su correspondiente ip interna.

Comment: Gracias tu respuesta me ha servido bastante ya puedo dejar los DNS de Google y acceder a los dominios locales. :)

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se consulta la resolución DNS de un nombre se confía en la respuesta del primer servidor DNS contactado.

Si los servidores DNS de google no tienen conocimiento de tu dominio devolverán un `NXDOMAIN` (Non-Existent Domain o dominio no existente) y tu equipo no podrá navegar por dicho dominio, ***no consultará el resto de servidores DNS configurados***.

---

**La solución ideal**

Sería que tus equipos configuraran como DNS primario y secundario dos controladores de dominio de tu empresa que tuvieran el rol de servidor DNS o únicamente el servidor DNS que tengas montado en tu empresa.

Por su lado, ese servidor debe tener activada la resolución DNS normal (es el funcionamiento por defecto de la mayoría de servidores DNS, consultaría los servidores raíz y procedería de manera habitual con el resto de dominios que no aloje o pueda responder de manera autoritativa) y/o configurar como padres los servidores DNS de google.

---

**Edito**

Si el servidor DNS de tu empresa filtra o bloquea dominios en su servidor tienes la opción de instalar un servidor DNS en tu equipo (u otro equipo) para agregar el dominio local configurando como servidor de reenvío el servidor DNS de tu empresa.

Así, las resoluciones normales las mandaría hacia Internet (tengas configurado o no el reenvío a los de google) y las de tu dominio local (y subdominios) se enviarán al servidor de tu empresa.

Ten en cuenta que esas políticas de bloqueo se ponen por algún motivo. Consulta al administrador de red de tu empresa para conocer qué implicaciones tendría saltarse dichas políticas.